# AVAudioPlayer stops returning correct currentTime after app goes to background

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have an issue which has been bugging me for few months now.

I have a running `Timer` which prints the `AVAudioPlayer's` currentTime, it all goes well unless I

> pause the player
>
> minimise the app or lock the screen
>
> resume playback

The time that is printed is suddenly constant. Sound is properly playing but the `currentTime` is not changing anymore unless I pause the player and call `play()` again.

Also, the worst part is that it does not happen every time, sometimes I have to repeat those steps 2/3 times but the bug happens eventually.

I have read the documentation and searched for some answers but there is nothing.

```
private func setTimer(_ on: Bool) {
    guard on else {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        return
    }
    guard timer == nil else { return }

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
        self.currentPlaybackTime = self.player.currentTime
        print("Delegate newTime: \(self.player.currentTime)")

    })
}

func play() {
    print("Tries playing")
    guard player.prepareToPlay(),
            player.play() else {
        playbackState = .failed
        return
    }
    print("Playing OK")
    setTimer(true)
    playbackState = .playing
}
```

Console prints

> Delegate newTime: 68.74916099773243 Delegate newTime:
>   68.74916099773243 Delegate newTime: 68.74916099773243 Delegate newTime: 68.74916099773243 Delegate newTime: 68.74916099773243
>   Delegate newTime: 68.74916099773243 ...

EDIT: `player.isPlaying` returns `false` when the time stays the same, it returns correctly `true` when time is correctly increasing

Why would `AVAudioPlayer` do this to me? It's clear that the timer works in the background and player causes the issue here.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have been working on it for a couple of weeks. It appears that the player.currentTime does not increment in the background. If I find a solution I will post an answer.

Comment: It's been quite some time since I solved this issue and if I remember correctly it had something to do with not handling the background audio interruptions correctly. I believe that when I properly paused and resumed AVAudioSession the player started working as expected. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773692/7235585

Comment: So far so good. I want say 'solved' until I test fully.
I have added code when my sleep timer ends 
            do
            {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            }
            catch
            {
               NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
            }
and the same but with true where the lock screen play control restarts play and it seems to be working.
Lots more testing before I'm convinced after so long stuck on this.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to deactivate and activate the 'AVAudioSession'.
When the app goes in to the background and when the playback is stopped iOS is setting the AVAudioSession's active state to false so you need to set it back to true if you use the lock screen controls to restart playback.
What I did (following the advice from Adam in the comment above) is set the false status when I stop playback then set to true when the user starts playback from the lock screen controls or via the play button on earbuds.

```
       do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        }
        catch
        {
           NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I have tested this in my own app and after weeks of attempts the functionality is now correct.